# Facing issue on SQL Server with Elastic Search

Tags: java, sql-server, elasticsearch

I have integrated SQL Server with Elastic Search. I face the problem with data type `TEXT` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

If I use any of this datatype in SQL Server, no result is returned by Elastic Search.

- Why does this happen?
- Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I fixed this issue by using JDBC Importer. https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc